# How to prove set property

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Question is how to prove that the first part is smaller or equal to the second part using set properties only:

A\C+B\A+C\B<=AuBuC

"\" as subtraction of sets and "u" as composite of sets

I understand it's true using Venns diagram but I can't figure out how to formally prove it.

Comment: And + is... union?

Comment: take an element X inside the left-hand set, and prove that it's in the left-hand set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$A\setminus C\subset A$$
$$B\setminus A\subset B$$
$$C\setminus B\subset C$$
$$(A\setminus C)\cup (B\setminus A)\cup (C\setminus B)\subset A \cup B\cup C$$

Comment: I looked at some other similiar proofs and finally got it. Thanks a lot!